# JVM crash after opening STS

Tags: java

I have updated STS (Spring Tool Suite) to 3.7, and now as I open STS it gets closed within 10-20 seconds.

I tried uninstalling-installing STS, also I tried rebooting my machine but still it getting closed.

Following is Log:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x000000006d97ea75, pid=3824, tid=5644
#
# JRE version: 6.0_35-b10
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (20.10-b01 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [jvm.dll+0xcea75]
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x00000000002c3000):  VMThread [stack: 0x0000000006220000,0x0000000006320000] [id=5644]

siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, reading address 0x00000000493931fa

Registers:
RAX=0x000000004939314a, RBX=0x00000000c5d1efd0, RCX=0x0000000000000000, RDX=0x3962212949394906
RSP=0x000000000631f670, RBP=0x0000000000000000, RSI=0x000000000060b2f0, RDI=0x0000000006df3b90
R8 =0x0000000000000006, R9 =0x0000000006df3b90, R10=0x00000000000001fe, R11=0x00000000c5d1f690
R12=0x0000000000214c10, R13=0x000000000020b040, R14=0x000000000060db40, R15=0x0000000000000012
RIP=0x000000006d97ea75, EFLAGS=0x0000000000010202

Top of Stack: (sp=0x000000000631f670)
0x000000000631f670:   00000000c5d1dfc4 000000006d9c3b40
0x000000000631f680:   0000000000000003 0000000000000000
0x000000000631f690:   00000000c5d1e880 000000006d9b8eb2
0x000000000631f6a0:   0000000000000003 0000000000214c10
0x000000000631f6b0:   0000000006df3b90 000000000060b2f0
0x000000000631f6c0:   00000000c5d1e880 000000006db030cb
0x000000000631f6d0:   00000000c6da2180 00000000c5d1f308
0x000000000631f6e0:   00000000c5d1df80 00000000c5d1df80
0x000000000631f6f0:   0000000000214c10 000000006dc78b40
0x000000000631f700:   0000000000000000 0000000000214b80
0x000000000631f710:   000000000060b2f0 000000006dfcc1e0
0x000000000631f720:   0000000000206f40 000000006dc868d2
0x000000000631f730:   000000006de7c068 0000000000000000
0x000000000631f740:   000000006dfcc1e0 0000000000000c01
0x000000000631f750:   0000000000010100 0000000000000000
0x000000000631f760:   000000000060c000 0000000000000000 

Instructions: (pc=0x000000006d97ea75)
0x000000006d97ea55:   cf 66 00 00 74 16 8b 43 08 0f b6 0d db 77 63 00
0x000000006d97ea65:   48 d3 e0 48 03 05 c9 77 63 00 eb 04 48 8b 43 08
0x000000006d97ea75:   0f b6 80 b0 00 00 00 24 07 3c 05 74 15 49 83 f8
0x000000006d97ea85:   01 75 0f 48 b8 00 ff ff ff 7f 00 00 00 48 85 d0 


Register to memory mapping:

RAX=0x000000004939314a is an unknown value
RBX=0x00000000c5d1efd0 is an oop
{constMethod} 
 - klass: {other class}
 - method:       0x00000000c5d1f010 {method} 'traverse' '(Lorg/eclipse/wst/jsdt/internal/compiler/ASTVisitor;Lorg/eclipse/wst/jsdt/internal/compiler/lookup/BlockScope;)V' in 'org/eclipse/wst/jsdt/internal/compiler/ast/LocalDeclaration'
 - exceptions:   0x00000000c0001ef8
RCX=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
RDX=0x3962212949394906 is an unknown value
RSP=0x000000000631f670 is an unknown value
RBP=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
RSI=0x000000000060b2f0 is an unknown value
RDI=0x0000000006df3b90 is an unknown value
R8 =0x0000000000000006 is an unknown value
R9 =0x0000000006df3b90 is an unknown value
R10=0x00000000000001fe is an unknown value
R11=0x00000000c5d1f690 is an oop
{instance class} 
 - klass: {other class}
R12=0x0000000000214c10 is an unknown value
R13=0x000000000020b040 is an unknown value
R14=0x000000000060db40 is an unknown value
R15=0x0000000000000012 is an unknown value


Stack: [0x0000000006220000,0x0000000006320000],  sp=0x000000000631f670,  free space=1021k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
V  [jvm.dll+0xcea75]

[error occurred during error reporting (printing native stack), id 0xc0000005]

VM_Operation (0x000000000da1eb10): ParallelGCFailedAllocation, mode: safepoint, requested by thread 0x00000000081e4800


---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
  0x0000000008ae7800 JavaThread "Reporting Thread-1 (Spring UAA/1.0.3)" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4652, stack(0x0000000012aa0000,0x0000000012ba0000)]
  0x0000000008ae6800 JavaThread "Worker-8" [_thread_blocked, id=3248, stack(0x00000000129a0000,0x0000000012aa0000)]
  0x00000000081e5800 JavaThread "AsyncHttpClient-Reaper" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2380, stack(0x00000000128a0000,0x00000000129a0000)]
  0x00000000081ea800 JavaThread "AsyncHttpClient-Reaper" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1340, stack(0x00000000127a0000,0x00000000128a0000)]
  0x00000000081e9000 JavaThread "New I/O client worker #5-1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2256, stack(0x00000000126a0000,0x00000000127a0000)]
  0x00000000081ee000 JavaThread "pool-6-thread-1" [_thread_blocked, id=3908, stack(0x0000000012310000,0x0000000012410000)]
  0x00000000081ec800 JavaThread "Timer-5" [_thread_blocked, id=4556, stack(0x0000000012210000,0x0000000012310000)]
  0x00000000081ec000 JavaThread "SVN Kit 1.7 Connector" [_thread_blocked, id=2820, stack(0x00000000125a0000,0x00000000126a0000)]
  0x00000000081ed800 JavaThread "Timer-2" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=880, stack(0x0000000012410000,0x0000000012510000)]
  0x00000000081e2800 JavaThread "Worker-7" [_thread_blocked, id=5860, stack(0x0000000011660000,0x0000000011760000)]
  0x00000000081e8800 JavaThread "Worker-6" [_thread_blocked, id=3540, stack(0x0000000011560000,0x0000000011660000)]
  0x00000000081e7800 JavaThread "Event Batch Processing (Spring UAA/1.0.3)" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4848, stack(0x0000000011460000,0x0000000011560000)]
  0x00000000081e7000 JavaThread "Synchronizer (Spring UAA/1.0.3)" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3280, stack(0x0000000011360000,0x0000000011460000)]
  0x00000000081e6000 JavaThread "Worker-5" [_thread_blocked, id=4912, stack(0x0000000011780000,0x0000000011880000)]
  0x00000000081e3000 JavaThread "Worker-4" [_thread_blocked, id=5076, stack(0x0000000011260000,0x0000000011360000)]
  0x00000000081df000 JavaThread "JavaScript indexing" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5788, stack(0x000000000da20000,0x000000000db20000)]
  0x00000000081e4800 JavaThread "Worker-3" [_thread_blocked, id=3768, stack(0x000000000d920000,0x000000000da20000)]
  0x00000000081e1000 JavaThread "Worker-2" [_thread_blocked, id=6088, stack(0x000000000db20000,0x000000000dc20000)]
  0x00000000081e0800 JavaThread "Java indexing" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4876, stack(0x000000000d820000,0x000000000d920000)]
  0x00000000081e2000 JavaThread "Worker-1" [_thread_blocked, id=3224, stack(0x000000000d250000,0x000000000d350000)]
  0x00000000081df800 JavaThread "Worker-0" [_thread_blocked, id=4696, stack(0x000000000b3e0000,0x000000000b4e0000)]
  0x0000000008b81000 JavaThread "Thread-1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5500, stack(0x000000000abb0000,0x000000000acb0000)]
  0x0000000009494000 JavaThread "Worker-JM" [_thread_blocked, id=4492, stack(0x000000000aab0000,0x000000000abb0000)]
  0x0000000008a71800 JavaThread "[Timer] - Main Queue Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2364, stack(0x000000000a8f0000,0x000000000a9f0000)]
  0x0000000008fd2800 JavaThread "Framework Event Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4712, stack(0x00000000096e0000,0x00000000097e0000)]
  0x0000000008a72000 JavaThread "Start Level Event Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2636, stack(0x0000000008380000,0x0000000008480000)]
  0x0000000008f5d000 JavaThread "Bundle File Closer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2172, stack(0x00000000095e0000,0x00000000096e0000)]
  0x0000000006d2f800 JavaThread "State Data Manager" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6052, stack(0x0000000008510000,0x0000000008610000)]
  0x00000000070ff800 JavaThread "Framework Active Thread" [_thread_blocked, id=536, stack(0x0000000008280000,0x0000000008380000)]
  0x000000000649f000 JavaThread "Low Memory Detector" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5940, stack(0x0000000006b20000,0x0000000006c20000)]
  0x0000000006492800 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1140, stack(0x0000000006a20000,0x0000000006b20000)]
  0x000000000647e800 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5584, stack(0x0000000006920000,0x0000000006a20000)]
  0x000000000647b000 JavaThread "Attach Listener" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=908, stack(0x0000000006820000,0x0000000006920000)]
  0x0000000006476000 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1904, stack(0x0000000006720000,0x0000000006820000)]
  0x0000000006425800 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2876, stack(0x0000000006620000,0x0000000006720000)]
  0x00000000002cb000 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4608, stack(0x0000000006320000,0x0000000006420000)]
  0x000000000060c000 JavaThread "main" [_thread_blocked, id=5880, stack(0x0000000002370000,0x0000000002470000)]

Other Threads:
=>0x00000000002c3000 VMThread [stack: 0x0000000006220000,0x0000000006320000] [id=5644]
  0x00000000064b0800 WatcherThread [stack: 0x0000000006c20000,0x0000000006d20000] [id=3904]

VM state:at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread:  ([mutex/lock_event])
[0x000000000060a4f0] Threads_lock - owner thread: 0x00000000002c3000
[0x000000000060a9f0] Heap_lock - owner thread: 0x00000000081e4800

Heap
 PSYoungGen      total 237440K, used 13833K [0x00000000f0000000, 0x0000000100000000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 213696K, 0% used [0x00000000f0000000,0x00000000f0000000,0x00000000fd0b0000)
  from space 23744K, 58% used [0x00000000fd0b0000,0x00000000fde32540,0x00000000fe7e0000)
  to   space 24064K, 0% used [0x00000000fe880000,0x00000000fe880000,0x0000000100000000)
 PSOldGen        total 82432K, used 71026K [0x00000000d0000000, 0x00000000d5080000, 0x00000000f0000000)
  object space 82432K, 86% used [0x00000000d0000000,0x00000000d455c8a0,0x00000000d5080000)
 PSPermGen       total 145856K, used 129324K [0x00000000c0000000, 0x00000000c8e70000, 0x00000000d0000000)
  object space 145856K, 88% used [0x00000000c0000000,0x00000000c7e4b0b8,0x00000000c8e70000)

Code Cache  [0x0000000002480000, 0x0000000002b30000, 0x0000000005480000)
 total_blobs=2579 nmethods=1708 adapters=823 free_code_cache=43573440 largest_free_block=77888

Dynamic libraries:
0x0000000000400000 - 0x000000000042f000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_35\bin\javaw.exe
0x0000000077550000 - 0x00000000776fa000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
0x0000000077330000 - 0x000000007744f000     C:\Windows\system32\kernel32.dll
0x000007fefd6e0000 - 0x000007fefd74b000     C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
0x000007feff270000 - 0x000007feff34b000     C:\Windows\system32\ADVAPI32.dll
0x000007fefdb40000 - 0x000007fefdbdf000     C:\Windows\system32\msvcrt.dll
0x000007feff580000 - 0x000007feff59f000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\sechost.dll
0x000007fefd9b0000 - 0x000007fefdadd000     C:\Windows\system32\RPCRT4.dll
0x0000000077450000 - 0x000000007754a000     C:\Windows\system32\USER32.dll
0x000007fefd940000 - 0x000007fefd9a7000     C:\Windows\system32\GDI32.dll
0x000007fefdff0000 - 0x000007fefdffe000     C:\Windows\system32\LPK.dll
0x000007feff090000 - 0x000007feff15a000     C:\Windows\system32\USP10.dll
0x000007feff830000 - 0x000007feff85e000     C:\Windows\system32\IMM32.DLL
0x000007feff160000 - 0x000007feff269000     C:\Windows\system32\MSCTF.dll
0x000000006d8b0000 - 0x000000006e069000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_35\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll
0x000007fefae80000 - 0x000007fefaebb000     C:\Windows\system32\WINMM.dll
0x000000006d820000 - 0x000000006d82e000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_35\jre\bin\verify.dll
0x000000006d450000 - 0x000000006d477000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_35\jre\bin\java.dll
0x000000006d870000 - 0x000000006d882000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_35\jre\bin\zip.dll
0x000007fefcb90000 - 0x000007fefcba8000     C:\Windows\system32\CRYPTSP.dll
0x000007fefc890000 - 0x000007fefc8d7000     C:\Windows\system32\rsaenh.dll
0x000007fefd5a0000 - 0x000007fefd5be000     C:\Windows\system32\USERENV.dll
0x000007fefd3a0000 - 0x000007fefd3af000     C:\Windows\system32\profapi.dll
0x000007fefd310000 - 0x000007fefd31f000     C:\Windows\system32\CRYPTBASE.dll
0x000000006d6b0000 - 0x000000006d6c7000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_35\jre\bin\net.dll
0x000007fefe000000 - 0x000007fefe04d000     C:\Windows\system32\WS2_32.dll
0x000007fefef60000 - 0x000007fefef68000     C:\Windows\system32\NSI.dll
0x000007fefcb30000 - 0x000007fefcb85000     C:\Windows\system32\mswsock.dll
0x000007fefcb20000 - 0x000007fefcb27000     C:\Windows\System32\wship6.dll
0x000007fefaf30000 - 0x000007fefaf45000     C:\Windows\system32\NLAapi.dll
0x000007fef9d80000 - 0x000007fef9d95000     C:\Windows\system32\napinsp.dll
0x000007fef9db0000 - 0x000007fef9dc9000     C:\Windows\system32\pnrpnsp.dll
0x000007fefc9b0000 - 0x000007fefca0b000     C:\Windows\system32\DNSAPI.dll
0x000007fef9d70000 - 0x000007fef9d7b000     C:\Windows\System32\winrnr.dll
0x000007fefc540000 - 0x000007fefc547000     C:\Windows\System32\wshtcpip.dll
0x000007fefab10000 - 0x000007fefab37000     C:\Windows\system32\IPHLPAPI.DLL
0x000007fefaad0000 - 0x000007fefaadb000     C:\Windows\system32\WINNSI.DLL
0x000007fefa440000 - 0x000007fefa448000     C:\Windows\system32\rasadhlp.dll
0x000007fefa7e0000 - 0x000007fefa833000     C:\Windows\System32\fwpuclnt.dll
0x0000000072000000 - 0x0000000072012000     D:\Softwares\springsource3\sts-3.1.0.RELEASE\plugins\org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.200.v20120913-144807\eclipse_1503.dll
0x000007fefb920000 - 0x000007fefbb14000     C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.7601.18837_none_fa3b1e3d17594757\COMCTL32.dll
0x000007fefef70000 - 0x000007fefefe1000     C:\Windows\system32\SHLWAPI.dll
0x000007fefc470000 - 0x000007fefc47c000     C:\Windows\system32\VERSION.dll
0x000007fefbd70000 - 0x000007fefbdc6000     C:\Windows\system32\uxtheme.dll
0x000007feff370000 - 0x000007feff573000     C:\Windows\system32\ole32.dll
0x000000006d6d0000 - 0x000000006d6db000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_35\jre\bin\nio.dll
0x0000000010000000 - 0x00000000100a8000     D:\Softwares\springsource3\sts-3.1.0.RELEASE\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\1850\1\.cp\swt-win32-4236.dll
0x000007fefe050000 - 0x000007fefe128000     C:\Windows\system32\OLEAUT32.dll
0x000007fefeec0000 - 0x000007fefef57000     C:\Windows\system32\comdlg32.dll
0x000007fefe130000 - 0x000007fefeeb9000     C:\Windows\system32\SHELL32.dll
0x000007fef9440000 - 0x000007fef94b1000     C:\Windows\system32\WINSPOOL.DRV
0x000007fefdbe0000 - 0x000007fefde0c000     C:\Windows\system32\WININET.dll
0x000007fefd5c0000 - 0x000007fefd5c4000     C:\Windows\system32\api-ms-win-downlevel-user32-l1-1-0.dll
0x000007fefd3b0000 - 0x000007fefd3b5000     C:\Windows\system32\api-ms-win-downlevel-advapi32-l1-1-0.dll
0x000007fefd580000 - 0x000007fefd584000     C:\Windows\system32\api-ms-win-downlevel-shlwapi-l1-1-0.dll
0x000007fefd530000 - 0x000007fefd534000     C:\Windows\system32\api-ms-win-downlevel-version-l1-1-0.dll
0x000007fefd590000 - 0x000007fefd593000     C:\Windows\system32\api-ms-win-downlevel-normaliz-l1-1-0.dll
0x0000000077710000 - 0x0000000077713000     C:\Windows\system32\normaliz.DLL
0x000007feff5a0000 - 0x000007feff82e000     C:\Windows\system32\iertutil.dll
0x000007fefd3c0000 - 0x000007fefd52d000     C:\Windows\system32\CRYPT32.dll
0x000007fefd390000 - 0x000007fefd39f000     C:\Windows\system32\MSASN1.dll
0x000007fefb5a0000 - 0x000007fefb5b8000     C:\Windows\system32\dwmapi.dll
0x000007fefbf10000 - 0x000007fefc03c000     C:\Windows\system32\propsys.dll
0x000007fefeff0000 - 0x000007feff089000     C:\Windows\system32\CLBCatQ.DLL
0x0000000007220000 - 0x000000000723e000     D:\Softwares\springsource3\sts-3.1.0.RELEASE\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\1850\1\.cp\swt-gdip-win32-4236.dll
0x000007fefb700000 - 0x000007fefb916000     C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.windows.gdiplus_6595b64144ccf1df_1.1.7601.19061_none_2b299db671e86e03\gdiplus.dll
0x000007fefb3f0000 - 0x000007fefb551000     C:\Windows\system32\WindowsCodecs.dll
0x0000000180000000 - 0x0000000180011000     D:\Softwares\springsource3\sts-3.1.0.RELEASE\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\1245\1\.cp\os\win32\x86_64\localfile_1_0_0.dll
0x000007fef05e0000 - 0x000007fef05f1000     D:\Softwares\springsource3\sts-3.1.0.RELEASE\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\1248\1\.cp\jWinHttp-1.0.0.dll
0x000007fefa8f0000 - 0x000007fefa961000     C:\Windows\system32\WINHTTP.dll
0x000007fefa880000 - 0x000007fefa8e4000     C:\Windows\system32\webio.dll
0x000007fefa7c0000 - 0x000007fefa7d1000     C:\Windows\system32\dhcpcsvc6.DLL
0x000007fefaa20000 - 0x000007fefaa38000     C:\Windows\system32\dhcpcsvc.DLL
0x000007feede30000 - 0x000007feede84000     C:\Windows\system32\oleacc.dll
0x000007fefd320000 - 0x000007fefd334000     C:\Windows\system32\RpcRtRemote.dll
0x000007fefd150000 - 0x000007fefd1a7000     C:\Windows\system32\apphelp.dll
0x000007fef9090000 - 0x000007fef90cb000     C:\Windows\system32\mlang.dll
0x000007fef6870000 - 0x000007fef6877000     C:\Windows\system32\msimg32.dll
0x000007fef6690000 - 0x000007fef685a000     C:\Windows\system32\explorerframe.dll
0x000007fefbd20000 - 0x000007fefbd63000     C:\Windows\system32\DUser.dll
0x000007fefb600000 - 0x000007fefb6f2000     C:\Windows\system32\DUI70.dll
0x000007fefc440000 - 0x000007fefc46d000     C:\Windows\system32\ntmarta.dll
0x000007fefdae0000 - 0x000007fefdb32000     C:\Windows\system32\WLDAP32.dll
0x000007fefb1e0000 - 0x000007fefb260000     C:\Windows\system32\ntshrui.dll
0x000007fefcef0000 - 0x000007fefcf13000     C:\Windows\system32\srvcli.dll
0x000007fefde10000 - 0x000007fefdfe7000     C:\Windows\system32\SETUPAPI.dll
0x000007fefd540000 - 0x000007fefd576000     C:\Windows\system32\CFGMGR32.dll
0x000007fefd620000 - 0x000007fefd63a000     C:\Windows\system32\DEVOBJ.dll
0x000007fef8b00000 - 0x000007fef8b0f000     C:\Windows\system32\cscapi.dll
0x000007fefac80000 - 0x000007fefac8b000     C:\Windows\system32\slc.dll
0x0000000011d30000 - 0x0000000011d40000     C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\TortoiseStub.dll
0x0000000011eb0000 - 0x0000000011f97000     C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\TortoiseSVN.dll
0x000007fef70b0000 - 0x000007fef70b7000     C:\Windows\system32\SHFOLDER.dll
0x000000006eec0000 - 0x000000006eeea000     C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\libapr_tsvn.dll
0x0000000068090000 - 0x0000000068133000     C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.5570_none_08e72cf3a83ac624\MSVCR90.dll
0x0000000068040000 - 0x0000000068082000     C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\libaprutil_tsvn.dll
0x0000000011d80000 - 0x0000000011d90000     C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\intl3_tsvn.dll
0x0000000067f40000 - 0x0000000068013000     C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.5570_none_08e72cf3a83ac624\MSVCP90.dll
0x000007fefc7c0000 - 0x000007fefc7cc000     C:\Windows\system32\netutils.dll
0x000007fef68d0000 - 0x000007fef68dc000     C:\Windows\system32\LINKINFO.dll
0x000007fef2360000 - 0x000007fef237d000     C:\Windows\system32\mssprxy.dll
0x000000006d0a0000 - 0x000000006d264000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_35\jre\bin\awt.dll
0x00000000118e0000 - 0x0000000011918000     C:\Users\amoghs\AppData\Local\Temp\jna\jna1764463035946726767.dll
0x0000000077720000 - 0x0000000077727000     C:\Windows\system32\PSAPI.DLL
0x0000000074b40000 - 0x0000000074b43000     C:\Windows\system32\Security.dll
0x000007fef88a0000 - 0x000007fef89c5000     C:\Windows\system32\dbghelp.dll

VM Arguments:
jvm_args: -XX:+UseFastAccessorMethods -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6 -Xms40m -Xmx768m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.IEVersion=10001 
java_command: D:\Softwares\springsource3\sts-3.1.0.RELEASE\\plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -showsplash -launcher D:\Softwares\springsource3\sts-3.1.0.RELEASE\STS.exe -name STS --launcher.library D:\Softwares\springsource3\sts-3.1.0.RELEASE\\plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.200.v20120913-144807\eclipse_1503.dll -startup D:\Softwares\springsource3\sts-3.1.0.RELEASE\\plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar --launcher.overrideVmargs -exitdata 15c0_5c -product org.springsource.sts.ide -vm C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.6.0_35/bin/javaw.exe -vmargs -XX:+UseFastAccessorMethods -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6 -Xms40m -Xmx768m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.IEVersion=10001 -jar D:\Softwares\springsource3\sts-3.1.0.RELEASE\\plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD

Environment Variables:
PATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;E:\Downloads\depot_tools\depot_tools;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Minimal ADB and Fastboot;C:\adb;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.0\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Users\amoghs\AppData\Roaming\npm
USERNAME=amoghs
OS=Windows_NT
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=Intel64 Family 6 Model 42 Stepping 7, GenuineIntel



---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS: Windows 7 , 64 bit Build 7601 Service Pack 1

CPU:total 4 (2 cores per cpu, 2 threads per core) family 6 model 42 stepping 7, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1, sse4.2, popcnt, ht

Memory: 4k page, physical 8286804k(5005264k free), swap 16571772k(13365104k free)

vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (20.10-b01) for windows-amd64 JRE (1.6.0_35-b10), built on Aug 28 2012 16:50:10 by "java_re" with MS VC++ 8.0 (VS2005)

time: Thu Apr 07 19:13:30 2016
elapsed time: 24 seconds
```

Can somebody help?

Comment: Update your Java installation if possible, then try again. Yours is antique.

Comment: @Axel, as I am facing this issue on my office machine so cant update without IT infra permission but ita very strange from last 2 years its working on that same Java version. Why stooped suddenly?